# this.Invoke(...) - is this bad practice?

Tags: c#

I have a function called ExecuteCommand that does things based on a user's input. These things can range from simply doing a Console.Writeline(), checking a check box on my form, or simulating keystrokes to another process, completely independent from my own. The function runs on a separate thread, so changing the UI will requiring some invoking. I have 2 ways of doing it... one of which I'm not sure is a good way but it's very easy.

Code below, the 3rd line is what I have a question with:

```
private void ExecuteCommand()
{
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
   {
      if (current_line_index < command_que.Count)
      {
         current_line = command_que[current_line_index];

         if (current_line.StartsWith(">>Auto Enter"))
         {
            chkAutoEnter.Checked = false;
         }
         else if (current_line.StartsWith("+WinWait("))
         {
            string title_to_wait_for = current_line;

            title_to_wait_for = title_to_wait_for.Remove(0, "+WinWait(\"".Length);          
            title_to_wait_for = title_to_wait_for.Remove(title_to_wait_for.Length - 2, 2);

            t_WinWait = new Thread(() => WinWait(title_to_wait_for));
            t_WinWait.Name = "WinWait";
            t_WinWait.Start();
         }
      }
   });
}
```

The code works perfectly... but I am not sure if it's good practice.

Alternativly, I know I can do something like this to change the UI:

```
private delegate void CheckCheckBoxHandler(bool checked);

private void CheckCheckBox(bool checked)
{
   if (this.chkAutoEnter.InvokeRequired)
   {
       this.chkAutoEnter.Invoke(new CheckCheckBoxHandler(this.CheckCheckBox), checked);
   }
   else
   {
       chkAutoEnter.Checked = checked;
   }
}
```

But as I have multiple controls on my form that will be changed from another thread, I'd have to add a bunch of functions to do that, versus the simple method in the first example.

Is the first way bad in anyway? Are there any risks involved I haven't come across yet? It seems to good to be true...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not bad.  It doesn't matter which control that you call `Invoke` on since they all have the same effect.   `Invoke` calls the delegate on the thread that owns the control - as long as all your controls are owned by the same thread, then there is no difference.