# C#: Thread Safe Serial Input

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I am designing a program to take an input from a serial hand scanner and compare it to a combobox filled with part numbers. The hand scanner reads a data matrix and compares it to the selected part. Here is the code currently

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        SerialPort serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(components);
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM10";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 57600;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        } // end form1()

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        textBox1.Text = indata;

        if (indata == comboBox1.Text)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        } // end datareceivedhandler

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.Close();

        } // end button2_Click

    } // end class
```

I am able to get the data to the variable "inData"  but get this error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I have looked up the posts on how to make thread safe calls, but I honestly just don't get it. Any assistance or explaining how to do this so I am able to learn would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Link I found to tell me exactly what I needed [this.Invoke(…) - is this bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028767/this-invoke-is-this-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the exception because you can not access the gui from any other but the UI thread. Use `this.Invoke` to run your code in the context of the main thread.

Extra tip: define an "end of input" sequence, for example have the scanner send CRLF at the end of each barcode. Append to a `StringBuilder` everything you get from the serial port until the data you receive contains CRLF. (that is: make the `StringBuilder` an instance variable and allow for the event to be called multiple times). Only then handle the barcode.

The thing is that serial input data may be highly fragmented. We often get only 3 or 4 chars per event.

Comment: Perfect. I was honestly just looking in the the wrong threads because I found one with exactly what I needed after reading your response.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mind my tip on how to read from a scanner - it will come handy :-)